# $f$ has square root if and only if image of $f_*$ contained in $2 \mathbb Z$

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space that is connected and locally path connected, and let $f : (X,x) \to (S^1,1)$ be a continuous map. Prove that $f$ has a square root (a continuous mapping $g : X \to S^1$ such that $g(x)^2=f(x)$, where the squaring operation comes from complex multiplication) if and only if the image of $f_* : \pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_1(S^1,1) \cong \mathbb Z$ is contained in $2\mathbb Z$.

---

Can I receive some hints on this? I am unsure how to express $g^2=f$ in terms of the map $f_*$ between the fundamental groups of $X$ and $S^1$, or something.

Comment: If such a solution exists you can observe f has image inside 2Z since its the postcomposition with a degree 2 map from S1 to itself. For the converse, use the lifting criterion for the two sheeted covering of S1 by itself.

Comment: The map $z \mapsto z^2 : S^1 \to S^1$ is the covering projection corresponding to the subgroup $2\Bbb{Z}$ of $\pi_1(S^1) = \Bbb{Z}$. $f$ "has a square root" if it factors through this map (and the theory of covering projections tells you when this happens).

Comment: If $q:S^1\to S^1$ is given by $q(z)=z^2$, then I would need to show that the image of $q_∗$ must be contained in $2\mathbb Z$? I am not sure how this map "corresponds" to $2 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @user525051 Think of an element in the fundamental group of the circle which generates the group. This can be chosen to be identity map on the circle. When you do $z \to z^2$ , you effectively are doing the product of the identity map with itself in the fundamental group.